# How do I progress? (I want to split up my SpriteKit methods into different Classes)

Tags: class, sprite-kit

So I just recently started to program and I already made a pretty big mistake. I started making a SpriteKit game but I used methods incorrectly (at least I think I did).

In my project there are three different "scenes" (is it scenes or views? what's the difference), one for the menu, the game scene itself and an options section.

Instead of splitting them up in first place (say: for each scene a different Class file with it's own implementation and header file) I sort of just made one big Class (MyScene.m/h) and called methods to switch to other scenes.

E.g.
In the Sprite Kit touchesBegan method I have this code

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"startGame"]) {

    [self gameScene]
```

and it would then go to my gameScene method:

```
-(void)gameScene{

//game code

}
```

It actually worked fairly well, but since the project is getting bigger and bigger I figured that it's getting to messy.

So how do I progress now? Can I call variables from other classes and if so, how?

I hope you understand my problem more or less..
It's not that I don't know how to program I just don't know how to deal with the project files. (since it's not really mentioned in the books I read to teach myself how to program..)

Comment: Your question is way too broad in scope to give you even a partially meaningful answer. You are asking help on some fundamental programming issues. I strongly suggest you read something like Objective-C Programming (Big Nerd Ranch) or some other book which deals in fundamentals. Otherwise you are just wasting your time. http://www.amazon.com/Objective-C-Programming-Ranch-Edition-Guides/dp/032194206X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1400526446&sr=8-1&keywords=objective+c

Comment: As said, your question is too broad but I think you might find some answers in the official documentation : https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html. For example, in the introduction, they explain about views and scenes. There is even a "Best pratices" section on how to organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, your question is very broad, but in reference to the "Can I call variables from other classes and if so, how?" part, I think what you're asking is in reference to "instance variables" or "iVars" for short.

When you create a class lets say the Player class, you of course have the interface (.h) file and the implementation (.m) file.

In the Player.h file you can define properties. These properties will then be available to access via "getter" and "setter" methods which are created automatically for you (as of xCode 4.4 i believe). You'll also have a iVar of the property available in the implementation file.

Example:

**Player.h**

```
@interface Player : SKNode

@property int health;
@property NSString *playerName;

@end
```

**Player.m**

```
@implementation Player

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _health = 100;
        _playerName = @"foo";

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Note: the leading underscore in front of the ivar, we don't have to give it a type because we already did that in the header file.

In you're scene were you create on object of your new class you can now access the information you defined as properties. Of course you need to import you're new class with #import "Player.h"

MyScene.m

```
Player *thePlayer = [[Player alloc]init];
NSString *myPlayerName = thePlayer.playerName;
```

This is a core concept to understand, hope this helps! :)